# Silverlight dynamic column with checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

I'm a new to mvvm, and try to learn. So I create new project and learning, but: I have a problem with Silverlight with checkboxes (spending two days) I don't know, how to bind checboxes in silverlight mvvm.

In my xaml file I have

```
        <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="List_ServicessProcess" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Summary[0].Total}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Summary[0].Total}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
```

In my C# code:

```
public class SaleData
{
    public int Categoryid { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public List<YearSummary> Summary { get; set; }
}

public class YearSummary
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }
    public List<OnWarehouse> Warehouse { get; set; }
}

public class OnWarehouse
{
    public bool yes { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var data = GetData();
        List_ServicessProcess.ItemsSource = data;
        var firstRow = data.First();

        for (int i = 0; i < firstRow.Summary.Count; i++)
        {
            var monthlySummary = firstRow.Summary[i];
            List_ServicessProcess.Columns.Add(CreateColumn(i, monthlySummary.Year.ToString()));
        }
    }

    public static List<SaleData> GetData()
    {
        List<SaleData> data = new List<SaleData>();
        data.Add(new SaleData() { Category = "Laptop Toshiba xyz", Summary = GetSummaryData() });
        data.Add(new SaleData() { Category = "Laptop Toshiba xyz", Summary = GetSummaryData() });
        data.Add(new SaleData() { Category = "Laptop Toshiba yzx", Summary = GetSummaryData() });
        data.Add(new SaleData() { Category = "Laptop Toshiba yzx", Summary = GetSummaryData() });
        data.Add(new SaleData() { Category = "Laptop Toshiba yzx", Summary = GetSummaryData() });
        return data;
    }

    private static List<YearSummary> GetSummaryData()
    {
        List<YearSummary> data = new List<YearSummary>();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var summary = new YearSummary() { Total = rnd.Next(-5000, 10000), Year = 2008 + i, Warehouse = GetWarehouse() };
            data.Add(summary);
        }

        return data;
    }

    private static List<OnWarehouse> GetWarehouse()
    {
        List<OnWarehouse> data = new List<OnWarehouse>();

        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            var summary = new OnWarehouse() { yes = (i % 2 == 0)};

            data.Add(summary);
        }
        return data;
    }

    private DataGridTemplateColumn CreateColumn(int index, string header)
    {
        string cellTemp = string.Format(@"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" 
            xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">
             <CheckBox IsChecked=""{{Binding Path=Warehouse[{0}].yes,Mode=TwoWay}}""/>
        </DataTemplate>", index);

        DataGridTemplateColumn column = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        column.Header = header;
        column.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(cellTemp);
        return column;
    }
}
```

When I start my simple project checkbox is not checked.

Finally result:

[finally result](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/545/7k28.png/)

Any help ? Thanks.
Jacobs

Comment: where are your checkboxes in xaml?

Comment: I add dynamic column in method CreateColumn and in is <CheckBox IsChecked=""{{Binding Path=Warehouse[{0}].yes,Mode=TwoWay}}""/>

Comment: It's too difficult to help me ? Maybye I repeat my question: How add checbox sometime is checked sometime not, when I created dynamic column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by your requirement, if I am understanding it correctly, you are showing whether the given `Category` was there in Warehouse in particular Year. I don't know why you have list of `OnWarehouse` in `YearSummary` here but considering that each row in your `DataGrid` is representing the `SaleData` and you are adding columns for each year depending on list of `YearSummary` in your `SalesData` then should not the xaml be like

```
string.Format(@"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" 
            xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">
             <CheckBox IsChecked=""{{Binding Path=Summary[{0}].Warehouse[0].yes,Mode=TwoWay}}""/>
        </DataTemplate>", index);
```

Comment: nit, thanks for repeat. Your suggestion resolved my problem :) Stupid logical error :).